# How to join two object arrays in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have two arrays of objects in my powershell script

First one has values likes this

```
@{Id=1, Count=24}
@{Id=2, Count=34}
```

Second

```
@{Id=1, Name="Some name"}
@{Id=2, Name="Some other name"}
```

I like to join these two so I get

```
@{Id=1, Count=24 Name="Some name"}
etc
```

Eventually I need to write it to a csv file.

Comment: Please edit the question and show how those are assigned values. Those variables look a bit like hash tables, but the syntax is not quite there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array has **objects** as you say like

```
$array1 = [PsCustomObject]@{Id=1; Count=24}, 
          [PsCustomObject]@{Id=2; Count=34}
$array2 = [PsCustomObject]@{Id=1; Name="Some name"}, 
          [PsCustomObject]@{Id=2; Name="Some other name"}
```

You can do something like this:

```
# this updates the objects in $array1
foreach ($item in $array1) {
    foreach ($obj in $item) {
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Name' -Value ($array2 | Where-Object { $_.Id -eq $obj.Id }).Name
    }
}

# show on screen
$array1

# export to CSV
$array1 | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\Joined.Csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output on screen:

```
Id Count Name           
-- ----- ----           
 1    24 Some name      
 2    34 Some other name
```

---

If the arrays store **Hashtables** like

```
$array1 = @{Id=1; Count=24}, 
          @{Id=2; Count=34}
$array2 = @{Id=1; Name="Some name"}, 
          @{Id=2; Name="Some other name"}
```

Then use this:

```
# this returns a new array of PSObjects
$result = foreach ($item in $array1) {
    foreach ($hash in $item) {
        $hash['Name'] = ($array2 | Where-Object { $_.Id -eq $hash.Id }).Name
    }
    [PsCustomObject]$hash
}

# show on screen
$result

# export to CSV
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\JoinedFromHashes.Csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output on screen:

```
Name            Id Count
----            -- -----
Some name        1    24
Some other name  2    34
```

<sup>Note that Hashtables are unordered by default, so the order in which the columns appear may vary</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Using this [`Join-Object`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join) cmdlet (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)) which both (custom) objects (including data tables) and hash tables:

```
Install-Module -Name JoinModule

$Array1 = @{Id=1; Count=24},
          @{Id=2; Count=34}
    
$Array2 = @{Id=1; Name="Some name"},
          @{Id=2; Name="Some other name"}
```

```
$Array1 | Join $Array2 -On Id
```

```
Count Id Name
----- -- ----
   24  1 Some name
   34  2 Some other name
```

Answer (score 1):

For posterity of people coming from google here's an idiomatic way of breaking the problem down.

```powershell
$first = $(
    @{Id=1; Count=24}
    @{Id=2; Count=34}
)
$second = $(
    @{Id=1; Name="Some name"}
    @{Id=2; Name="Some other name"}
)

$first,$second `
| %{ $_ } `
| To-Object `
| Group-Object -Property Id `
| %{ $_.Group | To-Hash | Merge } `
| To-Object `
| ConvertTo-Csv
```

If you want to keep them as hashtables and not get the CSV just yet, remove the last two lines, or if they were objects to begin with remove the first `To-Object`.

For which you'd need the following:

```powershell
Filter To-Object {
    $output = [PSCustomObject]@{}
    $_.GetEnumerator() `
    | %{
        $output `
        |  Add-Member `
            -Type NoteProperty `
            -Name $_.Name `
            -Value $_.Value
    }
    $output
}

Filter To-Hash {
    $out = @{}
    $in = $_
    $in `
    | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty `
    | %{
        $out[$_.Name] = $in.($_.Name)
    }
    $out
}

Function Merge {
    Begin {
        $output = @{}
    }
    Process {
        $_.GetEnumerator() `
        | %{
            $output[$_.Name] = $_.Value
        }
    }
    End {
        $output
    }
}
```

Not as efficient as my other answer (built-for-purpose) but these'll be much more useful for things outside of the asker's exact usecase, and much better for anyone learning powershell to have a look at :)

Comment: Interesting approach.  Ideas for improvements: 1) simplify `To-Object` to `{ New-Object PSCustomObject -Property $_ }` 2) ditch `To-Hash` by retooling `Merge` to work with objects.

Answer (score 0):

```powershell
$first = $(
    @{Id=1; Count=24}
    @{Id=2; Count=34}
)
$second = $(
    @{Id=1; Name="Some name"}
    @{Id=2; Name="Some other name"}
)

$first,$second `
| %{ $_ } `
| &{
    Param ($key)
    Begin {
        $output = @{}
        
        Function Input {
            Param ($id)
            Begin {
                $merged = $output[$id]
                if (!$merged) {
                    $merged = [PSCustomObject]@{$key=$id}
                }
            }
            Process {
                if ($_.Name -ne $key) {
                    $merged `
                    |  Add-Member `
                        -Type NoteProperty `
                        -Name $_.Name `
                        -Value $_.Value
                }
            }
            End {
                $output[$id] = $merged
            }
        }
    }
    Process {
        $_.GetEnumerator() `
        | Input -id $_[$key]
    }
    End {
        $output.Values
    }
} -key 'Id' `
| ConvertTo-Csv
```

Outputs

```powershell
Id Count Name
-- ----- ----
 2    34 Some other name
 1    24 Some name
```

Then

```powershell
"Id","Count","Name"
"2","34","Some other name"
"1","24","Some name"
```